# ''Want" vs "Need" Which one would be correct?

Tags: word-usage

Context:
'I don't need help from you' as I found at many places written this.
So, can I write this as I don't want your help?

Answer (score 2):

*Don't need* and *Don't want* mean different things, most of the time anyhow.

> > *I don't need help from you*

means that *I do not require your help*. I can manage without it.

But it's not usual to add *from you* unless it's specifically from the person addressed that you don't need help. And it sounds a bit pointed, as if you dislike the person or regard them as incapable. It would depend on the way you said it, whether you emphasised *from you*.

> > I don't want your help

means that I don't desire it. It makes clear that although you may require help, you definitely don't want it from the person concerned. It's a clear rejection of an offer of help that implies your dislike or poor opinion of the person offering it.

Comment: Additional thought: "I don't want your help" could also mean that although the person could benefit from help, they would prefer to do it themselves because doing it themself is important to them (no reflection on the other person).

Answer (score 1):

Although these are simple sentences, they may carry a great many different meanings, and in speech these would be distinguished by different emphases. My attempts below do not exhaust the possibilities, which would probably be further refined by tone, gesture and facial expression.

1."I DONT want your help" = stop bothering me, Ive already told you.

2."I dont WANT your help" = I prefer to do it myself, or I have to do my homework without help.

3."I dont want YOUR help" = I dont think that help from you would be much use, or I resent your condescending attitude.

4."I dont want your HELP" = I dont see how you can help, but some sympathy would be nice.

In most cases, both want and need would work. In case 2, though, "I dont NEED your help" could mean "Thank you, but I'm OK, I can do this myself" and could be said in a friendly way, where "I dont WANT your help" is more likely to express irritation.

I think this simple sentence displays a great deal of subtlety that in conversation would be conveyed non-verbally. In writing, it would benefit by being expanded in some way Thank you, No thank you, Ive already told you, I dont need any help from you, etc., etc. In either case, getting it right, and achieving the proper emotional tone, would indicate real mastery of the language.

Answer (score 0):

Wants and things that are not necessary for your livelihood essentially, so if you say, "I don't need your help." You are saying that my help is not necessary.
However, if you were to say, "I don't want your help." That refers to a desire, such as I want cookies. That means you do not desire my help.